# How to limit number of selected items in React hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

so I am building a small game with a table of numbers, and when a div is selected or deselected I am adding/removing a class to change the appearance of the selected item. My problem is that I would like to limit the number of selected items to 6. So if the user tries to select a 7th item, it will not toggle the class and I can return a notification.

***EDIT***: I am not sure why it isnt showing the code for "Ball" correctly, but Ball returning this div:

```
    <div id={value}
         data-number={value}
         onClick={()=>setSelected(!selected)}
         className={`Ball ${selected ? 'numberIsSelected' : ''}`}>
        {value}
    </div>
```

This is my current code for Ball:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

export default function Ball({value}) {

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

    return(
        setSelected(!selected)}
             className={`Ball ${selected ? 'numberIsSelected' : ''}`}>
            {value}
        
    )
}
```

and contents of "export default function GameTable()" :

```
const size = 7;
let number = 1
const Count = function () {
    return number++
}
let rows = [];
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++){
    let rowID = `row${i}`
    let cell = []
    for (let idx = 0; idx < size; idx++){
        let cellID = `cell${i}-${idx}`
        cell.push(<Ball key={cellID} value={Count()} />)
    }
    rows.push(<div className="numbers-row" key={rowID} id={rowID}>{cell}</div>)
}
return(
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12 board">
                <div id="numbers-list" className="numbers-list">
                    <div className="numbers-inner">
                        {rows}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: I would probably use contextAPI to handle that... the event function would refer to the context if it can select or not and which ones are selected by cellID

Comment: @Noriller, thanks for the tip. Do you have an example of how I would use it in my case? I am trying to get my head around it I am really novice

Answer (score 0):

something like this i believe...

```js
const SelectedContext = createContext({
  selected: [],
  onSelect: () => { },
  isSelected: () => { },
});

export function ProvideSelected({ children }) {
  const { selected, isSelected, onSelect } = useProvideSelected();

  return (
    <SelectedContext.Provider value={{ selected, isSelected, onSelect }}>
      {children}
    </SelectedContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useSelected() {
  return useContext(SelectedContext);
}

function useProvideSelected() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  function isSelected(id) {
    return selected.includes(id);
  }

  function onSelect(id) {
    if (isSelected(id)) setSelected([selected.filter(x => x !== id)]);

    if (selected.length > 6) throw new Error('too many selected');

    setSelected([...selected, id]);
  }

  return { selected, isSelected, onSelect };
}
```

then you consume the context and use its functions to check if its selected and to select/unselect the items

check the documentation on how to use context if you never used: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: this is a really great starting point for me on my game. I am still playing around to get it all working properly in my code, but I do have it creating the array of picked numbers now and throwing an error when > 6 are selected. I also see how this will be useful for the rest of my game functions. I am unable to pick your answer or even upvote you because of my low rep. But huge thanks to you this is the path I needed to get on.